# Joining two lists (alternating)

Tags: list

I have two lists that I am joining but running into issues.

First list is called header

```
header= list(last)
header
```

> ['AMC', 'AMD', 'EDU', 'F', 'FCEL', 'LCID']

Second list is called
`lastlist= lastr.values.tolist()`

`lastlist`

> [[22.418, 1.627, 0.121, 2.365, 1.019, 4.574]]

To add the two lists to gether, we use the zip function.

`master = []`

`for sym, num in zip(header, lastlist):`
`master.append(' '.join((sym, num)))`

`print(master)`

However, unfortunately I get this error:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-195-33ee9da2ea12> in <module>`
 `2  3 for sym, num in zip(header, lastlist): ----> 4     master.append(' '.join((sym, num))) 5  6 print(master)`

`TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, list found`

I get the error above. I want to my new list to be in this format

master = [AMC 22.418, AMD 1.627,...]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Yasser

Comment: @DanielHao also answered this question earlier. Thank You Daniel.

Comment: Also reopen last answer for you to compare. The numbers in `lastlist` are `string` in last Post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one instead, you miss some quote *`(`* and **str(num):**

If there is any questions, please ask.

```
for sym, num in zip(header, lastlist[0]):
    master.append((' '.join((sym, str(num)))))
    
print(master)
```

Output:

```
['AMC 22.418', 'AMD 1.627', 'EDU 0.121', 'F 2.365', 'FCEL 1.019', 'LCID 4.574']
```

Comment: THIS IS IS MAGIC HOW YOU DO THIS???

Comment: And Thank You! Also you helped me with this on the other thread. You have full credit. Thank You again.